# Text-hover-blur with CSS3?

Tags: html, css

Whenever I hover over my box, it's supposed to blur the img, turn down the brightness of the img down 60%, and then some text will appear. Which does work however, whenever I hover over the text, the blur goes away and the text remains in the box until I hover out of it. I was wondering how I can fix this so everything can react simultaneously?

html Code:
`

```
<section class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <figure class="col-sm-6">
      <img src="edge.jpg">
      <h2>COBAN Technologies</h2>
      <h4>Quality Control Specialist</h4>
</section>
```

`

CSS code:

```
    /*work panels*/

section .col-sm-6 img {
  margin: 0 0 30px 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

section .col-sm-6 img:hover {
  filter: blur(2px) brightness(60%);

}

section .col-sm-6 :not(img) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

section .col-sm-6:hover :not(img) {
  opacity: 1;
}

section .col-sm-6 h4 {
  top: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your hover line to

```
section .col-sm-6:hover img {
  filter: blur(2px) brightness(60%);
}
```

So that you apply the style if you hover the whole element containing both the text and image, instead of when hovering only the `<img>`.

```css
    /*work panels*/

section .col-sm-6 img {
  margin: 0 0 30px 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

section .col-sm-6:hover img {
  filter: blur(2px) brightness(60%);
}

section .col-sm-6 :not(img) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

section .col-sm-6:hover :not(img) {
  opacity: 1;
}

section .col-sm-6 h4 {
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <figure class="col-sm-6">
      <img src="https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/avatar300s/a96ecf5e524449ec866a6674709bb212.jpg">
      <h2>COBAN Technologies</h2>
      <h4>Quality Control Specialist</h4>
    </figure>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: No problem @Justin